# How to rename a table in SQLite 3.0?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, rename, table-rename

How do you rename a table in [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) 3.0?

Answer (score 282, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `foo` RENAME TO `bar`
```

[SQLite Query Language: ALTER TABLE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

Answer (score 5):

The answer remains to use "ALTER TABLE". But the main documentation page on this topic is pretty thick. What is needed is a simple example of how that works. You can find that here: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-alter-table/

To be precise, in the most basic case it looks like this:

```
ALTER TABLE existing_table
RENAME TO new_table;
```

I am not sure if the dot notation works, but I assume that the following is also correct:

```
ALTER TABLE existing_database.existing_table
RENAME TO new_database.new_table;
```

If you have spaces in the name, then you need to backticks that are included in the first accepted answer... so you may need something like this if you have spaces.

```
ALTER TABLE `existing databasename`.`existing tablename`
RENAME TO `newer databasename`.`newer tablename`;
```

Comment: Another distinction between this answer and the accepted answer (relevant to my use-case anyway) is that you do not need the single back-quotes around the old and new names (so long as they don't contain spaces I imagine).

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can change(rename) the table name `apple` to `orange` as shown below:

```sql
ALTER TABLE apple RENAME TO orange;
```

And, you need to use `""` for the table name with `.` as shown below. *The table name with `.` happened to me when converting a PostgreSQL dump file to a SQLite dump file with [RebaseData](https://www.rebasedata.com/convert-postgresql-to-sqlite-online):

```sql
            ↓            ↓
ALTER TABLE "public.apple" RENAME TO apple;
```