# How does sequelize.sync() work, specifically the force option?

Tags: sequelize.js

What does the force option on sequelize.sync() do?

```
sequelize.sync({
    force: true
});
```

Specifically, I am interested in knowing what force: false does? Will it not sync the schema with the database?

Are there any formal docs for sequelize? I could only find examples inside the docs.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

(More or less) formal docs and API reference can be found at https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#model-synchronization

To your question: `force: true` adds a `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` before trying to create the table - if you force, existing tables will be overwritten.

Comment: Additionally: if you change the table name (that already exist) of an Entity, the table stays with data, and another table with the new name is created.

Comment: This is not answering the question. The question asks what `force: false` does, not what `force: true` does.

Comment: I call sequelize.sync({force: false}), but still the tables are re-created. Why is this?

Comment: Link is dead. That's the reason why (stand-alone) links in answers should be avoided.

Answer (score 54):

The OP was asking what `force: false` does, which is what I wanted to know too, so here's the rest.

**The major takeaway, for me, was that the individual fields aren't synced (which is what I was hoping for, coming from the Waterline ORM). Meaning, if you have `force: false` and the table exists, any field additions/modifications/deletions you have won't be executed.**

- `beforeSync` hooks are run
- table is dropped if `force: true`
- table is created with `if not exists`
- indexes are added if necessary
- `afterSync` hooks are run

Here's the [current code from the github repo](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/3e5b8772ef75169685fc96024366bca9958fee63/lib/model.js#L974) for reference:

**`lib.model.js`**

```js
Model.prototype.sync = function(options) {
  options = options || {};
  options.hooks = options.hooks === undefined ? true : !!options.hooks;
  options = Utils._.extend({}, this.options, options);

  var self = this
    , attributes = this.tableAttributes;

  return Promise.try(function () {
    if (options.hooks) {
      return self.runHooks('beforeSync', options);
    }
  }).then(function () {
    if (options.force) {
      return self.drop(options);
    }
  }).then(function () {
    return self.QueryInterface.createTable(self.getTableName(options), attributes, options, self);
  }).then(function () {
    return self.QueryInterface.showIndex(self.getTableName(options), options);
  }).then(function (indexes) {
    // Assign an auto-generated name to indexes which are not named by the user
    self.options.indexes = self.QueryInterface.nameIndexes(self.options.indexes, self.tableName);

    indexes = _.filter(self.options.indexes, function (item1) {
      return !_.some(indexes, function (item2) {
        return item1.name === item2.name;
      });
    });

    return Promise.map(indexes, function (index) {
      return self.QueryInterface.addIndex(self.getTableName(options), _.assign({logging: options.logging, benchmark: options.benchmark}, index), self.tableName);
    });
  }).then(function () {
    if (options.hooks) {
      return self.runHooks('afterSync', options);
    }
  }).return(this);
};
```

Answer (score 6):

**Minimal runnable example**

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: 'tmp.sqlite',
});
(async () => {
const IntegerNames = sequelize.define('IntegerNames', {
  value: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, },
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, },
}, {});
//await IntegerNames.sync({force: true})
await IntegerNames.create({value: 2, name: 'two'});
await sequelize.close();
})();
```

Setup:

```
npm install sequelize@6.5.1 sqlite3@5.0.2.
```

On stdout we can see the queries it did:

```
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `IntegerNames`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `IntegerNames` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `value` INTEGER, `name` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL);
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`IntegerNames`)
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `IntegerNames` (`id`,`value`,`name`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (NULL,$1,$2,$3,$4);
```

If we use `force: false` instead we get the same except there's no `DROP` at the start:

```
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `IntegerNames` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `value` INTEGER, `name` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL);
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`IntegerNames`)
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `IntegerNames` (`id`,`value`,`name`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (NULL,$1,$2,$3,$4);
```

And if we remove sync the table does not get created at all:

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `IntegerNames` (`id`,`value`,`name`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (NULL,$1,$2,$3,$4);
```

**Conclusion: `force`**

- `force: false`: if the table exists, nothing happens to it due to `IF NOT EXISTS` in `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`. Therefore any table schema modifications are ignored.
- `force: true`: the table is dropped first, so any schema changes take effect `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`. But you lose all data

**`alter: true, force: false` actually attempts to keep data and modify the database**

With `force: true`, the database gets dropped and recreated, so of course it matches the latest schema, but you lose all data.

To try to keep existing data and update the schema, we have to use `alter: true` in addition to `force: false`.

The following works and stdout shows the convoluted sequence of queries used to make it work by creating a temporary database `IntegerNames_backup`:

```
const assert = require('assert')
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

function getSequelize() {
  if (process.argv[2] === 'p') {
    return new Sequelize('tmp', undefined, undefined, {
      dialect: 'postgres',
      host: '/var/run/postgresql',
    })
  } else {
    return new Sequelize({
      dialect: 'sqlite',
      storage: 'tmp.sqlite',
    })
  }
}

(async () => {
{
  const sequelize = getSequelize()
  const IntegerNames = sequelize.define('IntegerNames', {
    value: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, },
    name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, },
  }, {});
  await IntegerNames.sync({force: true})
  await IntegerNames.create({value: 2, name: 'two'});
  await IntegerNames.create({value: 3, name: 'three'});
  await sequelize.close();
}

// Alter by adding column.
{
  const sequelize = getSequelize()
  const IntegerNames = sequelize.define('IntegerNames', {
    value: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, },
    name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, },
    nameEs: { type: DataTypes.STRING, },
  }, {});
  await IntegerNames.sync({
    alter: true,
    force: false,
  })
  await IntegerNames.create({value: 5, name: 'five' , nameEs: 'cinco'});
  await IntegerNames.create({value: 7, name: 'seven', nameEs: 'siete'});
  const integerNames = await IntegerNames.findAll({
    order: [['value', 'ASC']],
  });
  assert(integerNames[0].value  === 2);
  assert(integerNames[0].name   === 'two');
  assert(integerNames[0].nameEs === null);
  assert(integerNames[1].name   === 'three');
  assert(integerNames[1].nameEs === null);
  assert(integerNames[2].name   === 'five');
  assert(integerNames[2].nameEs === 'cinco');
  assert(integerNames[3].name   === 'seven');
  assert(integerNames[3].nameEs === 'siete');
  await sequelize.close();
}
})();
```

If we remove `alter: true` it blows up because the new column doe not exist:

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: table IntegerNames has no column named nameEs
```

On PostgreSQL it actually produces `ALTER` statements, which is awesome:

```
Executing (default): ALTER TABLE "public"."IntegerNames" ADD COLUMN "nameEs" VARCHAR(255);
Executing (default): ALTER TABLE "IntegerNames" ALTER COLUMN "value" DROP NOT NULL;ALTER TABLE "IntegerNames" ALTER COLUMN "value" DROP DEFAULT;ALTER TABLE "IntegerNames" ALTER COLUMN "value" TYPE INTEGER;
Executing (default): ALTER TABLE "IntegerNames" ALTER COLUMN "name" DROP NOT NULL;ALTER TABLE "IntegerNames" ALTER COLUMN "name" DROP DEFAULT;ALTER TABLE "IntegerNames" ALTER COLUMN "name" TYPE VARCHAR(255);
Executing (default): ALTER TABLE "IntegerNames" ALTER COLUMN "createdAt" SET NOT NULL;ALTER TABLE "IntegerNames" ALTER COLUMN "createdAt" DROP DEFAULT;ALTER TABLE "IntegerNames" ALTER COLUMN "createdAt" TYPE TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;
Executing (default): ALTER TABLE "IntegerNames" ALTER COLUMN "updatedAt" SET NOT NULL;ALTER TABLE "IntegerNames" ALTER COLUMN "updatedAt" DROP DEFAULT;ALTER TABLE "IntegerNames" ALTER COLUMN "updatedAt" TYPE TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;
```

We see that it just runs an `ALTER` statement for every column separately, even if the column already exists, in which case it does not get modified in any way.

On SQLite, the way alter works is by creating a new table, and moving all data from the old table to the new one through:

```
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `IntegerNames_backup` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, `value` INTEGER, `name` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `nameEs` VARCHAR(255));
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `IntegerNames_backup` SELECT `id`, `value`, `name`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `nameEs` FROM `IntegerNames`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE `IntegerNames`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `IntegerNames` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, `value` INTEGER, `name` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `nameEs` VARCHAR(255));
```

TODO why doesn't it use `ALTER` statements? SQLite seems to support them: [How do you rename a table in SQLite 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426495/how-do-you-rename-a-table-in-sqlite-3-0) This then breaks constraints which sequelize does not automatically drop and recreate as needed: [Process of changing a table with sequelize migration if foreign key constraint is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64533732/process-of-changing-a-table-with-sequelize-migration-if-foreign-key-constraint-i) it is quite sad.

**Conclusion: `alter`**

`alter: true` allows us to easily add new columns, or modify properties of existing columns.

Reasons why this cannot fully replace migrations: [Sequelize: Changing model schema on production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708620/sequelize-changing-model-schema-on-production)

- it simply cannot handle table or column renames, it just doesn't have enough information to know that the old and new column are the same. I think it would also not handle column deletions on PostgreSQL.
- it cannot intelligently add/remove/modify data as might be required during a migration (obviously). As a simple example, adding a `NOT NULL` constraint may require you to fill in some previously NULL buggy rows with some value of choice.

Comment: In February 2022, this is the most elaborate and descriptive answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want don't want to drop the table but want all the table updates (add/remove columns, etc) you can use

```
sequelize.sync({ force: false, alter: true })
```

force can be used in a development environment but not in production as it will drop the table first and create again, alter will match the existing model and change the table accordingly. Alter is also not advisable in production as will delete data of the columns removed or type changed, but if you want to avoid migrations and update your table this is the option.

Comment: There is more to check at: https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/models/model-synchronization/